# MongoDB cache aggregation stages

Tags: mongodb, caching, mongoose

I am currently using Mongoose for a project and I am trying to optimize a few aggregating queries.
Using caching in order to cache the results is pretty straightforward for MongoDB as:

```
const res = cache.get(key);
if (res) {
  return res;
}
MyModel.aggregate([]).then(docs => {
  cache.add(key, docs);
});
```

But in my scenario, I have a bunch of aggregations that have similar heavy operations at the very first stages of their pipeline

```
const c = MyModel.aggregate([
  {$match : {},}}
  {$project :{}},
  {$unwind :{}},
  // extra stages for c
]);

const d = MyModel.aggregate([
  {$match : {},}}
  {$project :{}},
  {$unwind :{}},
  // extra stages for d
]);
```

I have optimized my schemas with indexes and the `allowDiskUse` option and I am looking for a bit more juice.

Is there any way to populate the first stages of a pipeline using a caching mechanism or even a way to pipe aggregations? Does MongoDB cache any results within the stage pipeline?

Moving transformations to the client side is not an option as I want to use a much power as I can from my database.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you thought about using an [`$out`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/#pipe._S_out) stage to populate a temporary collection with the "heavy operations" output so that you can reuse that result?

Comment: You could as well check out $facet which allows you to run some the first common part of your query and then base some other pipelines on top of that. Not sure if that is applicable in your specific case but it's a powerful feature sometimes: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/

Comment: @JohnnyHK This makes sense. The `$out` stage operator is used at the end of the pipeline though. It requires double checking across two collections in order to sink the data and since there is no way to pipe aggregations I don't think that's the proper way to handle caching. I have a feeling that MongoDB internally caches the stages across pipelines but I could not find any further documentation.

Comment: @dnickless Facets are great indeed but still is there any way to prepopulate the data for repetetive stages across multiple aggregations or even a way to pipe aggregation results?

Comment: I would say: No, there isn't. MongoDB/WiredTiger perform some level or smart caching, of course but that would be only around input/source data not transformed/processed data. `$out` is probably your friend here if you need a break in between the runs, e.g. if you cache stuff today but need the results tomorrow or something. Otherwise, as I wrote before, I would probably look into `$facet`.

Answer (score 3):

I have found a solid way to cache aggregations based on JohnnyHK's comment.

I have used a temporary collection with [TTL indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-ttl/)

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const s = mongoose.Schema({ 
  // ...
}, {timestamps: true});
s.index({createdAt: 1},{expireAfterSeconds: 3600});

const CachingModel = mongoose.model('Cache', s);

const getData = async () => {
  await Model1.aggregate([
    {$match : {}}
    {$project :{}},
    {$unwind :{}},
    {$out: 'Cache'}
  ]);

  return Promise.all([
    CachingModel.aggregate([
      // #1 aggregate the matching results
    ]),

    CachingModel.aggregate([
      // #2 aggregate the matching results
    ])
  ];
}
```